# How to store generic function pointer as `any` in Rust?

Tags: function, pointers, generics, rust, any

I'm building a crate that takes functions as inputs.

I'd like to hide the type of the function so `Scope` does not need to be generic.

This should be okay because function pointers are a "copy" type and are static.

```rust
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
struct Scope {
   caller: &'static dyn Any,
   props_id: TypeId
}

impl Scope {
    fn new<T: 'static>(f: fn(T)) -> Self {
        let caller = f as &'static dyn Any;
        let props_id = TypeId::of::<T>();
        Self { caller, props_id }
    }

    fn call<T: 'static>(&self, val: T) {
        let caller = self.caller.downcast_ref::<fn(T)>().unwrap();
        caller(val);
    }
}
```

However, I cannot take a `&'static` to the function pointer, and I cannot use the guarantees of `any` without using a box. I would like to not use a box because the type of `fn()` *is* known.

How would I go about solving this problem, perhaps even leveraging some unsafety with function pointers to get this working?

I could transmute the pointer type, but I am looking for something a little less hard to misuse.

Answer (score 1):

You can take `&'static fn(T)` [instead](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dd006117e311f1f8d94061347f05582c).  I don't think there's a way to cast a function pointer itself to `&dyn Any`.